# best method for horizontal web display?

Tags: jquery, css, html, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I have a new project in front of me and I have to create a horizontal display of 7 pages. The middle page would be the main page and to the left and to the right there would be 3 other pages. Its my first time with a horizontal display.

What method would be the best and most direct way?! Do people have ideas for this?!

Thanks for the help

Comment: If web designers created books instead, they'd probably create novels where the pages open in all four directions and the text spins in a circle while you're trying to read it. Then they'd blame the publisher when they're told it's not printable.

Comment: I really have'nt began. I wanted to see what techniques there can be to gain this. I will also need every page to adapt to the screen resolution. which method could there be?!

Comment: A simple googling yielded: 
[this](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/),
[this](http://www.thewebsqueeze.com/web-design-tutorials/create-a-horizontal-scrolling-website.html),
and [this](http://woork.blogspot.mx/2009/02/useful-tips-to-design-horizontal.html)

Comment: Try this showcase site for horizontal scrolling http://www.thehorizontalway.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will get you started:

**CSS**

```
html,
body
{
    height:100%;
}
body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:auto;
}
ul
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul li
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
}
ul li.page-1,
ul li.page-3,
ul li.page-5,
ul li.page-7
{
    background-color:#655;
}
ul li.page-2,
ul li.page-4,
ul li.page-6
{
    background-color:#855;
}
.clearfix:after
{
    clear:both;
    content:'.';
    display:block;
    font-size:0;
    height:0;
    line-height:0;
    visibility:hidden
}
.clearfix
{
    display:block;
    zoom:1
}​
```

**jQuery**

```
var width=$(window).width();

$('body').css('width',(width*7)+'px').scrollLeft((width*3));

$('ul li').css({'width':width+'px','height':$(document).height()+'px'});
```

​
**HTML**

```
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li class="page-1">
        page 1
    </li><li class="page-2">
        page 2
    </li><li class="page-3">
        page 3
    </li><li class="page-4">
        page 4 (current)
    </li><li class="page-5">
        page 5
    </li><li class="page-6">
        page 6
    </li><li class="page-7">
        page 7
    </li>
</ul>​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vkqDm/)**

### Edit:

In order to navigate to the prev/next page add this:

**jQuery**

```
$('.prev').click(function()
{
    i=$(this).parent('li').index()-1;

    $('body').animate({scrollLeft:(width * i)});

    return false;
});

$('.next').click(function()
{
    i=$(this).parent('li').index()+1;

    $('body').animate({scrollLeft:(width * i)});

    return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li class="page-1">
        page 1
        <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
    </li><li class="page-2">
        page 2
        <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a> &middot; <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>    
    </li>
    ....
    <li class="page-7">
        page 7
        <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/vkqDm/1/)**

Comment: This seems a good beginning. Now I can get the thoery how it works and transform this... THANKS! As you can see the horizontal scrolling does work. But is there a way to make the scroll stop in each page? I mean, if there was a menu with links to the different pages, it would navigate to another page and stop in the page. This way the screen would be filled up by that page. You woudnlt need to scroll by hand to have it to fit into your screen...